# Rails multiple modules with a join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I have a Join table; ThingLocation for Event and Location and wants to add another mudule:Profile

thing_location.rb

```
class ThingLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :location
end
```

event.rb

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
has_many :thing_locations
has_many :locations, through: :thing_locations
end
```

location.rb

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
has_many :thing_locations
has_many :events, through: :thing_locations
end
```

All work fine until I wanted to add a third module: Profile to use available locations through the join table ThingLocation.

When I try to grab location in the profile update form it throws error ”Event must exist”

Removing **“belongs_to :event”** from the thing_locations.rb solves the *but this will remove the association between profiles and events*

....After adding a new model: Profiles

thing_location.rb

```
class ThingLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :location
belongs_to :profile

end
```

event.rb

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord

has_many :thing_locations
has_many :locations, through: :thing_locations

belongs_to:profile
end
```

location.rb

```
 class Location < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :thing_locations
 has_many :events, through: :thing_locations
 has_many :profiles, through: :thing_locations
 end
```

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
has_many :thing_locations
has_many :locations, through: :thing_locations

has_many :hows, dependent: :destroy

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found in rails 5, adding "optional: true" in the join module​ fixes the issue:

thing_location.rb

```
class ThingLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event, optional: true
belongs_to :location
belongs_to :profile, optional: true
```

end